# Why instanceof return false?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

Server.js

```
import Router from '@core/router/Router'

class Server {
  constructor () {
  }


  use (router) {
    if ((router instanceof Router) === false) {
      throw Error('You can only use a Router instance with Server::use')
    }

    this.router = router
  }
}

export default Server
```

app.js

```
import Server from '@core/Server/Server'
import router from '@auth/router'

var app = new Server()

app.use(router)

export default app
```

router.js

```
import Router from '@core/Router/router'

var router = new Router([
])

export default router
```

I get

> Error: You can only use a Router instance with Server::use
>       at Server.use (C:\Users\tom.cordelier\Desktop\chacha-emu\lib\core\Server\Server.js:89:15)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\tom.cordelier\Desktop\chacha-emu\lib\auth\app.js:21:5)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)

Look like instanceof didn't work properly, but `router.constructor.name` is good.

My .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "stage-2",
    "stage-3"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"],
      "alias": {
        "@core": "./src/core",
        "@auth": "./src/auth",
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

I think i miss understand something with export default.
Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: use debugging to see what the two operands really are. an if statement isn't going to give you a false result when the result is true.

Comment: You have `import Router from '@core/router/Router'` and `import Router from '@core/Router/router'` <-- why the different capitalization?

Comment: Yeah it's absolutely the capitalization. That will make Node see it as two separate files, and thus two separate classes, if you have a case-insensitive filesystem.